# Python Tkinter how to get the coordinates of an object which is in a different class

Tags: python, class, tkinter

So I am making a python `tkinter` game.

I have the following classes

```
class GameObject(object)
class Ball(GameObject)
class Paddle(GameObject)
class Brick(GameObject)
class Game(tk.Frame)
```

In the `class Ball` i am trying to obtain the current coordinates of the `paddle` but I am not sure what the syntax for that is (trying to get the coordinates of the paddle when the ball hits a brick).

I was able to get the coordinates for the ball easily by just doing `self.get_position()` in the ball class but I don't know how to access the paddle class.

Comment: maybe first create instance of some object and later send it to another class as argument. `paddle = Padle()`, `ball = Ball(padle)`

Comment: From the design point of view, checking collision should not be done inside `Ball` class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe first create instance of `Paddle` and later send it to `Ball` as parameter

```
paddle = Paddle() 
ball = Ball(paddle)
```

and you have to get it in `__init__`

```
class Ball(GameObject)

    def __init__(self, paddle):
        self.paddle = paddle
```

and later in `Ball` you can get its position

```
pos = self.paddle.get_position()
```

---

Other method is to get `paddle` as parameter only in functions which really need it.

```
class Ball(GameObject)

    def check_collision(self, paddle):
        if self.get_position() == paddle.get_position():
            # ...
```

and later you can check collision with different paddles (or other elements)

```
paddle_1 = Paddle() 
paddle_2 = Paddle() 

ball = Ball()

# ...

if ball.check_collision(paddle_1):
    #...

if ball.check_collision(paddle_2):
    #...
```